# Prevent style attributes from changing back to default as others are change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This snippet of code changes the brightness and contrast of an image. However, when setting the contrast to 150% for example and then attempting to change the brightness the contrast value defaults back to 100%. How can I prevent these style attributes from changing back to their default value after being changed?

```
<p>
   Contrast Bar
</p>
<input id='contrast_bar' type="range" min="50" max="150" value="100">
<p>
   Brightness Bar
</p>
<input id='brightness_bar' type="range" min="50" max="150" value="100">
<BR><BR>
<img id='img_selection' src="photo.jpg">
<script>
   let contrast_bar = document.querySelector('[id=contrast_bar]')
   let brightness_bar = document.querySelector('[id=brightness_bar]')
   let img = document.querySelector('#img_selection')

   contrast_bar.addEventListener('input', con_bar => {
     img.style.filter = 'contrast(' + con_bar.target.value + '%)'
   })

   brightness_bar.addEventListener('input', bright_bar => {
     img.style.filter = 'brightness(' + bright_bar.target.value + '%)'
   })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you overwrite the previous setting of `filter` when you change each range slider, therefore only ever one filter type is updated.

To fix the problem create a function which reads the values from both range inputs and creates a single string with *both* brightness and contrast values, and call this function any time either range is changed.

```js
let contrast_bar = document.querySelector('#contrast_bar');
let brightness_bar = document.querySelector('#brightness_bar');
let img = document.querySelector('#img_selection');
let updateFilter = () => img.style.filter = `contrast(${contrast_bar.value}%) brightness(${brightness_bar.value}%)`;

contrast_bar.addEventListener('input', updateFilter);
brightness_bar.addEventListener('input', updateFilter);
```

```css
img { width: 300px; }
```

```html
<p>Contrast Bar</p>
<input id="contrast_bar" type="range" min="50" max="150" value="100" />

<p>Brightness Bar</p>
<input id="brightness_bar" type="range" min="50" max="150" value="100" /><br /><br />

<img id="img_selection" src="https://i.imgur.com/WkomVeG.jpg" />
```